# How to set up a Goal Funnel with new Google Analytics. i.e. Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I just signed up for Google Analytics after watching some YouTube videos but the Google Analytics site looks totally different. Nonetheless, I was able to set up Goals but how do you set up Funnels for them? That option just isn't there anymore....

Comment: A quick search for "how to setup funnels with universal analytics" gives lots of answers to this.

Answer (score 1):

Funnels would be set up in the same page where you define your goal. In particular, you would need to define a destination goal, and then set the "Funnel option" on, and then define your funnel steps. More information can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en